# Symfony2 - postPersist does not happen after persist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

got another Symfony2 issue, more specifically postPersist does not seem to execute after the persist.

In my controller I have a createAction (removed some code)

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    try {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $alert = new AvailabilityAlert();
        $alert->setLastUpdated();
        $alert->setIsDeleted(0);
        $alert->setAlertStatus('Active');

        $em->persist($alert);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse('Success');

    }catch (Exception $e) {
    }

}
```

To this, I have an EventListener in place

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Service\UapiService;

class AvailabilityAlertListener
{
    protected $api_service;

    public function __construct(UapiService $api_service)
    {
        $this->api_service = $api_service;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
            $this->api_service->addFlightsAction($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this postPersist should execute after the AvailabilityAlert is persisted to the database?

Inside my listener I call a function addFlightsAction.  This function does a database query.  This query essentially selects the data I need where the id is equal to the id I pass it (the one created by new AvailabilityAlert() ).  To get this id, I use $entity->getId().

I have outputted the id and it is correct.  However, when I output the result from the database query I receive an empty array.  If however in my database query I do

```
$id = $entity->getId();
... query code
->setParameter('id', $id-1)
```

So take 1 away from the current id, the query returns the data from the last alert I inserted.  So this tells me that when I give it the alert id of the current alert and I get no data from this, the current alert has not been persisted to the database at the time this is happening.

Is there any way to resolve this?

p.s. My service

```
doctrine.availability_alert_listener:
        class: Nick\AlertBundle\EventListener\AvailabilityAlertListener
        arguments: [@alert_bundle.api_service]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

Thanks

Comment: did you define your class as doctrine.event.listener in services?

Comment: I define it as a tag e.g. - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }

Answer (score 0):

Since the inserts are happening in a transaction, which hasn't been committed yet, the records that you have just written may not yet be available to read back in.

If all the data you need to do the call to `addFlightsAction` is in the entity, you have the data available there. Alternatively, you may be able to gather the rest of the data that has just been written via `$args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();`

Otherwise, you could always just run the addFlight code after the flush, when the transaction has been committed.

Comment: I definitely need it to happen after the flush, because it relies on getting the data which is in the database.  I have tried doing it, but I dont understand what getUnitsOfWork is giving me.  Is there no way to use it to getEntity like I do in my code above?

Answer (score 0):

Fire your query in the postFlush event instead of the postPersist event, this should let you do $id-1 as you described above.

Keep in mind that postFlush args are a instance of `PostFlushEventArgs`, not `LifecycleEventArgs`